# Video is much faster than audio moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to merge audio with video using MoviePy.
Audio has larger duration than video, so I've changed it to the duration of video.

This is my code:

```
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip, VideoFileClip

video = 'youtube.mp4'
audio = 'voice.mp3'

nName = 'youtube2.mp4'

vClip = VideoFileClip(video)
aClip = AudioFileClip(audio)

print(vClip.duration)
print(aClip.duration)

fAudioClip = aClip.subclip(0.000, vClip.duration)

fVideoClip = vClip.set_audio(fAudioClip)

fVideoClip.write_videofile(nName, codec='libx264',audio_codec='aac')
```

Output-

```
*424.96
428.92
Moviepy - Building video youtube2.mp4.
MoviePy - Writing audio in youtube2TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp4
MoviePy - Done.                                                                 
Moviepy - Writing video youtube2.mp4

Moviepy - Done !                                                                
Moviepy - video ready youtube2.mp4*
```

But still, the video runs **much** faster than audio & gets over quickly. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Well, the durations of the audio and video clips clearly are not the same; what do you *expect* to happen?

Comment: Would you mind posting the results of `ffmpeg -i youtube.mp4`? I suspect that it is reading the fps incorrectly, so you could try doing `vClip = VideoFileClip(video, fps_source="fps")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should replace :

```
fAudioClip = aClip.subclip(0.000, vClip.duration)

fVideoClip = vClip.set_audio(fAudioClip)
```

by this :

```
fVideoClip = CompositeAudioClip([vClip.audio, aClip])
```